# limit on num of divs or memory for a webpage on iOS?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad, safari

I created a webpage that contains a list of posts (think facebook list view of posts). This webpage causes the safari browser on the iPad to crash. I'm not sure if this is because of too many divs in the page, or due to javascript of the page using up too much memory.

Any ideas on if there is a max number of divs, or maximum memory per page on iOS safari?
The webpage loads and performs normally on Chrome/FireFox/Safari-on-MacIntel

Comment: I'd try limiting the amount of images or other large resources. Also, if you have a lot of posts, try pagination.

Comment: iOS is pretty good at handling large DOM trees. However, be careful not to remove elements that are way out of sight, like removing the first 10 items in a list of posts that is 100 or so items long. We had crashes with this before. Other culprits are as TheZ mentioned large images. Remember that any pixel, even transparent ones, take up 4 byte in RAM. So even a one with a small file size can end up huge in memory.

Comment: Thanks all for the responses. For now, I'm using pagination as TheZ suggested. I'm also trying to reduce the number of images and divs to see if that helps, so I can show more per page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an EXACT number of divs. However I bet there is a limit.
I'd try limiting images or videos to bring down the amount of memory.
Your best bet is to keep the MB low for the iPAD since it doesn't have as much RAM as the Computer. 
Hopefully that helps.

There is no div limit, just over load ;)

Answer (score 0):

Cut some corners on the page; reduce image size/change formats, take off any 'fluff'. Remember, mobile sites aren't supposed to look and function like a desktop site. An efficient, minimal, clean mobile webpage is the way to go. You may be able to find some mobile jQuery plugins to help out too. As @TheZ mentioned, try Pagination.